# How can I run MongoDB as a Windows service?

Tags: mongodb, windows-services, nosql

How can I set up MongoDB so it can run as a Windows service?

Comment: Hmm. That is quite a bit more work than the accepted answer :-(.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I think if you run it with the `--install` command line switch, it installs it as a Windows Service.

```
mongod --install
```

It might be worth reading [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/fde13e7ceb64ac44/a39a7e1b711a6b00) first though. There seems to be some problems with relative/absolute paths when the relevant registry key gets written.

Comment: i finally managed to install by execute this:
mongod.exe --service

Comment: It seems like what you really need to do is enter the full path at the command line: c:\> c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --service.  However, make sure to run the command window as administrator (especially on windows server) otherwise you'll be thwarted by UAC.

Comment: this gist can be time saving for devleopment machine setups https://gist.github.com/serdarb/5102848

Comment: And after you run with --install, you'll have to `net start MongoDB`

Comment: this answer may be out of date.

Comment: Like @JCGrubbs said if you run as a regular user the command completes quietly without any errors but does not add a service. If you remember that, and follow these https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-the-mongodb-service you'll be fine.

Comment: It requires a logfile path, you can add the dbpath and logfile path like this mongod --dbpath="c:\data\db"  --logpath="c:\data\db\log.txt" --install ,  After this you need to run net start MongoDB.

Comment: do i need to do it per path of data? i start mongo, with hello world, and the tutorial were not just about mongo so the detail were a little. the way it did it, said go to the same path as you did, then generate a fol;ter and used --path command to send data of a collection to there... now should we lunch it per collection specifying the path? for example you lunch two application on server?

Comment: The answer should specify that you need to run `mongod --install` as an Administrator, otherwise it fails silently. As others have stated, you also need to `run net start MongoDB`.

Answer (score 388):

After trying for several hours, I finally did it.

## Make sure:

1. you added the `<MONGODB_PATH>\bin` directory to the system variable `PATH`
2. run command prompt as administrator

---

## Steps:

**step 1:** execute this command:

```
D:\mongodb\bin>mongod --remove
```

**Step 2:** execute this command after opening command prompt as administrator:

```
D:\mongodb\bin>mongod --dbpath=D:\mongodb --logpath=D:\mongodb\log.txt --install
```

NOTE: you can also append `--serviceName MongoDB` after the command above.

### That's All!

---

After that right there in the command prompt execute:

```
services.msc

// OR

net start MongoDB
```

And look for MongoDB service and click start.

---

**NOTE: Make sure to run command prompt as administrator.**

If you don't do this, your log file (`D:\mongodb\log.txt` in the above example) will contain lines like these:

```
2016-11-11T15:24:54.618-0800 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
2016-11-11T15:24:54.618-0800 I CONTROL  [main] Error connecting to the Service Control Manager: Access is denied. (5)
```

and if you try to start the service from a non-admin console, (i.e. `net start MongoDB` or `Start-Service MongoDB` in PowerShell), you'll get a response like this:

```
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.
```

or this:

```
Start-Service : Service 'MongoDB (MongoDB)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open MongoDB service
on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service MongoDB
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceComman
```

Comment: You can also start it with `net start MongoDB` instead of using `services.msc`. (`mongod` recommended that to me.)

Comment: This worked for me. The path to the log file has to be created manually if it doesn't already exist (I used a path other than the mongo directory in the example).

Comment: At first, Mongo started as a service, but my database was empty. I could only see my previously existing database by adding \data to the path : mongod --dbpath=D:\mongodb\data

Comment: "Make sure to run command prompt as administrator" - it did the job! Running with normal permission does not write any warning, but service is just not created. Permissions, permissions, permissions!

Comment: neither of the top 2 answers will keep the service running on reboot - see instead my answer below

Comment: `mongod --remove` was key for me, since I had an old install location, and `--install` didn't override with the new location on it's own.

Comment: Should be the validated answer

Answer (score 65):

not only `--install`,

also need `--dbpath` and `--logpath`

and after reboot OS you need to delete **"mongod.lock**" manually

Comment: +1 for deleting mongod.lock file. This still appears to be an issue with 1.8.1 running on 64-bit.

Comment: Better even to specify --config and define dbpath, logpath and other options there.

Comment: Appears that this `mongod.lock` bug is fixed on my `Windows 8 x64`

Answer (score 65):

Unlike other answers this will ..

**START THE SERVICE AUTOMATICALLY ON SYSTEM REBOOT / RESTART**

## MongoDB Install

### Windows

(1) Install MongoDB

(2) Add bin to path

(3) Create c:\data\db

(4) Create c:\data\log

(5) Create c:\data\mongod.cfg with contents ..

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

(6) To create service that will **auto start on reboot** .. **RUN AS ADMIN** ..

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\data\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

(7) Start the service .. RUN AS ADMIN ..

```
net start MongoDB
```

IMPORTANT: Even if this says 'The MongoDB service was started successfully' it can fail

To double check open Control Panel > Services, ensure the status of the MongoDB service is 'Running'

If not, check your log file at C:\data\log\mongod.log for the reason for failure and fix it

(Do not start MongoDB via Control Panel > Services, use .. net start MongoDB)

(8) Finally, restart your machine with MongoDB running and it will still be running on restart

If you ever want to kill it ..

```
net stop MongoDB

sc.exe delete MongoDB
```

Comment: thanks it worked for Me , I just had to change `3.4` to `3.6` version in this command `sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\data\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"`

Answer (score 33):

> The below steps apply to Windows.

Run below in an **administrative** `cmd`

```
mongod --remove
```

This will remove the existing MongoDB service (if any).

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\data\db" --logpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.log" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
```

Make sure that `C:\data\db` folder exists

Open services with:

```
services.msc
```

Find **MongoDB** -> Right click -> Start

Comment: Perfect!  Minor note, the folders must exist (at least the one for the logs).

Comment: Minor question regarding sidenote: Doesn't the file need to exist too? I can vaguely remember the absence of the (empty) file itself giving me problems.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the command below for running mongodb as a windows service

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod" --bind_ip  yourIPadress  --logpath  "C:\data\dbConf\mongodb.log"  --logappend  --dbpath  "C:\data\db"  --port yourPortNumber --serviceName "YourServiceName" --serviceDisplayName "YourServiceName" --install
```

If you use mongodb with default parameters, you can use these values :

- yourIPadress : 127.0.0.1 or localhost
- yourPortNumber : 27017 (default port) or dont put --port
- serviceDisplayName : only if you run more than one service (since mongodb 1.8)

There's more information on this command here

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service

Answer (score 17):

I tried all answers and then did it the way https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition describes it.

Use a config file...

`"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install`

Answer (score 14):

This PowerShell Script Downloads and Installs MongoDB as Windows Service:

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$mongoDbPath = "C:\MongoDB" 
$mongoDbConfigPath = "$mongoDbPath\mongod.cfg"
$url = "http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.9.zip" 
$zipFile = "$mongoDbPath\mongo.zip" 
$unzippedFolderContent ="$mongoDbPath\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.9"

if ((Test-Path -path $mongoDbPath) -eq $True) 
{ 
  write-host "Seems you already installed MongoDB"
    exit 
}

md $mongoDbPath 
md "$mongoDbPath\log" 
md "$mongoDbPath\data" 
md "$mongoDbPath\data\db"

[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("$mongoDbConfigPath", "dbpath=C:\MongoDB\data\db`r`n")
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("$mongoDbConfigPath", "logpath=C:\MongoDB\log\mongo.log`r`n")
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("$mongoDbConfigPath", "smallfiles=true`r`n")
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("$mongoDbConfigPath", "noprealloc=true`r`n")

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.DownloadFile($url,$zipFile)

$shellApp = New-Object -com shell.application 
$destination = $shellApp.namespace($mongoDbPath) 
$destination.Copyhere($shellApp.namespace($zipFile).items())

Copy-Item "$unzippedFolderContent\*" $mongoDbPath -recurse

Remove-Item $unzippedFolderContent -recurse -force 
Remove-Item $zipFile -recurse -force

& $mongoDBPath\bin\mongod.exe --config $mongoDbConfigPath --install

& net start mongodb
```

Answer (score 11):

This was the only thing that worked for me. As everything had to be an absolute path:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod --install --dbpath=c:/data/db --logpath=c:/data/logs/log.txt
```

I also had to run it from `admin cmd`

Answer (score 7):

The recommended way `mongod --install` results in error:

```
2015-12-03T18:18:28.896+0100 I CONTROL  --install has to be used with a log file for server output
```

After having installed mongodb in `C:\mongodb` you need to simply add the logpath:

```
mongod --install --logpath C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
```

The path to the logfile must exist and it must be an absolute Windows path. Then you start the MongoDB service by typing:

```
net start MongoDB
```

Answer (score 6):

**Working on Mongo DB: 3.6**

(1) Install MongoDB

(2) Add bin to environment path variable

(3) Create `c:\data\db`

(4) Create `c:\data\mongod.log`

(5) Run below Command on `bin` folder

> .\mongod.exe --install --logpath c:\data\mongod.log --logappend
>   --bind_ip 12
>   7.0.0.1 --dbpath c:\data\db

(6) To start mongo db as service

> net start MongoDB

(7) Finally run `mongo` in command line to check mongo shell is open or not.

Comment: Works also with mongod version 4.2.8. Thanks!

Comment: In step 5, if this error is thrown: `F  CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\log\mongod.log"` all that is needed is to delete `mongod.log` file

Answer (score 5):

Consider using

```
mongod --install --rest --master
```

Comment: consider to update your answer with ruby's answer (yours it is incomplete)

Answer (score 4):

For version 2.4.3 (current version as of posting date), create a config file and then execute the following:

`C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --config C:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg --service`

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "d:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=d:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.config" displayname= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
```

escaping the binPath was failing for me as described in the Mongo documentation

Failed:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
```

Comment: Run cmd as administrator and run this command: sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "d:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=d:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.config" displayname= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is,

1. Create folder `C:\data\db`
2. Create file `C:\data\db\log.txt`
3. Open command prompt as "Run as Administrator" and make sure the mogodb bin directory path is correct and write

   ```
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin> mongod.exe --install mongod --dbpath="c:\data\db" --logpath="c:\data\db\log.txt"
   ```
4. Start mongodb service:

   ```
   net run MongoDB
   ```

Comment: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 4):

Working on MongoDB 3.4 [Windows]

- Create dir C:/mongodb/data
- Create a file in C:/mongodb/mongodb.config using this configuration:

  ```
  storage:
      engine: wiredTiger
      dbPath: "C:/mongodb/data"
      directoryPerDB: true
      journal:
          enabled: true
  systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: "C:/mongodb/data/mongod.log"
      logAppend: true
      timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
  net:
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1
      port: 27017
      wireObjectCheck : false
  ```
- To install MongoDb as a service, run this command in powershell with admin power

  mongod --config="C:\mongodb\mongodb.config" --install --service
- Open Services.msc and look for MongoDb, then start it

Answer (score 3):

Currently (up to version 2.4.4), if any path (dbpath/logpath/config) contains spaces, then the service won't start, and show the error: "The service is not responding to the control function".

Answer (score 2):

I'm on version 2.4.9 and using a config file. The service wouldn't start until I surrounded the equals sign in the config file with spaces:

```
dbpath = D:\Mongo data
logpath = C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log 
logappend = true
```

Originally I had:

```
logpath=C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
```

I also discovered that when installing the service that you have to use an absolute path for the config file eg:

```
c:\mongodb\bin\>mongodb.exe C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.conf --install
```

Don't be tempted to put inverted commas around a *dbpath* with spaces.  The service will appear to start when you execute *net start MongoDB* but it will terminate.  Check the log files for confirmation that the service has really started.

Answer (score 2):

Run "cmd.exe" as administrator and then run "sc.exe" to add a new Windows service.

for example:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "c:\program files\mongodb\server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that you should pass : dbpath , config and logfile to mongod with the install flag

example :

```
mongod --dbpath=c:\data\db --config=c:\data\db\config.cfg --logpath=c:\data\db\log.txt --install
```

note : I have mongod path in my path variable .

You can control the service with :

```
net start mongodb
net stop  mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps to install MongoDB as Windows Service :

1. Create a log directory, e.g. `C:\MongoDB\log`
2. Create a db directory, e.g. `C:\MongoDB\db`
3. Prepare a configuration file with following lines

   `dbpath=C:\MongoDB\db`

   `logpath=C:\MongoDB\log`

   ***Place the configuration file with name mongod.cfg in folder "C:\MongoDB\"***
4. Following command will install the Windows Service on your 
   `sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg\" DisplayName= "MongoDB 3.4"  start= "auto"`
5. Once you run this command, you will get the `[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`
6. Run following command on Command Prompt

   `net start MongoDB`

Answer (score 1):

If you install MongoDB 2.6.1 or newer using the [MSI download](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) from an [Administrator Command Prompt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#open-an-administrator-command-prompt), a service definition should automatically be created for you.

The MongoDB documentation also has a tutorial to help you [Manually Create a Windows Service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb) definition if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who have already installed mongo DB using MSI installer.

Let's say your default installed location is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin"

Steps to run mongo as a window service

1. Open command prompt as administrator
2. Type `cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin` (check path properly, as you may have a different version installed, and not 3.2).
3. Press enter
4. Type `net start MongoDB`
5. Press enter
6. Press Windows + R, type `services.msc` and check if Mongo is running as a service.

Comment: Have correct path but getting error : `System error 2 has occurred. The system cannot find the file specified.` tried mongod , mongodb as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to restart the MongoDB (v4.4) service after editing the config file on a Windows box. Here's what I did:

1. Press `Win+R` to open the Run panel
2. Type in "services.msc" and press Enter
3. Search for "MongoDB" - you can press "m" to jump to it.
4. Right click - select "Restart"

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

```
mongod --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod_primary.cfg" --install --serviceName "MongoDB_Primary" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB Primary"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check windows services

   if you have service for mongo remove it by run bellow command 
    `mongod --remove`
2. create mongo.cfg file with bellow content

   systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
   storage:
   dbPath: c:\data\db

   path: where you want to store log datas 
   dbPath: your database directory
3. then run bellow command

   `sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"`

   binPath : mongodb installation directory
   config: .cfg file address 
   DisplayName:Your Service Name
4. start service

   `net start MongoDB`

**now every things are done . enjoy that**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create the mongod.cfg beside the mongd.exe with the following contents.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Then I run either the two command to create the service.

```
D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --config D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg --install

D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>net stop mongodb
The MongoDB service is stopping.
The MongoDB service was stopped successfully.


D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --remove
2019-04-10T09:39:29.305+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-04-10T09:39:29.309+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to remove Windows service 'MongoDB'
2019-04-10T09:39:29.310+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Service 'MongoDB' removed

D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>
D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg\""
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>net start mongodb
The MongoDB service is starting..
The MongoDB service was started successfully.

D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>
```

The following are not correct, note the escaped quotes are required.

```
D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod --config D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>net start mongodb
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.


D:\apps\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Plz try the steps in Mongo DB: 3.6 & Windows 10

1. `mongod --remove`
2. `mongod --dbpath=C:/data/db --port 27017 --logpath C:/data/log/log.txt --service`
3. `mongod --dbpath=C:/data/db --port 27017 --logpath C:/data/log/log.txt --install`
4. `net start MongoDB`

Comment: MongoDB 4.0 runs fine on Windows 64-bit ... UNLESS you try securing it by adding the "authorization: enabled" line to the "Security" setting in mongod.cfg. Then it results in windows reporting an error message "the service did not start in a timely manner". Any idea what's happening here?