# What is the correct way to start a mongod service on linux / OS X?

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, initialization

I've installed mongodb and have been able to run it, work with it, do simple DB read / write type stuff.  Now I'm trying to set up my Mac to run mongod as a service.

I get "Command not found" in response to:

```
 init mongod start
```

In response to:

```
~: service mongod start
service: This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead.
service: failed to start the 'mongod' service
```

And if I try:

```
~: launchctl start mongod
launchctl start error: No such process
```

So obviously I'm blundering around a bit. Next step seems to be typing in random characters until something works. The command which *does* work is: `mongod --quiet &` I'm not sure, maybe that is the way you're supposed to do it?  Maybe I should just take off 'quiet mode' and add `> /logs/mongo.log` to the end of the command line?

I'm building a development environment on a Mac with the intention of doing the same thing on a linux server.  I'm just not sure of the Bash commands.  All the other searches I do with trying to pull up the answer give me advice for windows machines.

Perhaps someone knows the linux version of the commands?

Thanks very much

Comment: I have done on Windows with this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service), not sure if same on Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks Scott, no I'd also seen and tried the stuff from your thread `error command line: unknown option install`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

With recent builds of mongodb community edition, this is straightforward.

When you install via brew, it tells you what exactly to do. There is no need to create a new launch control file.

```
$ brew install mongodb
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mongodb-3.0.6.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz ### 100.0%
==> Pouring mongodb-3.0.6.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mongodb now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.6: 17 files, 159M
```

Comment: Does `mongod` need to display information through the window server; does it need to be a _launch agent_ or is it enough to make it a _launch daemon_?

Comment: Heads up to OSX users: I installed mongo via homebrew and it included `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.5-x86_64/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` (and was properly configured for my installation). Just copied `homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` into LaunchAgents and followed the rest of these instructions (substituting `homebrew.mxcl.mongodb` for `org.mongodb.mongod`) and it works great.

Comment: You'd better scroll down for Mario Alemi's answer ;)

Comment: /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist: No such file or directory

Comment: First of all: MongoDB has it's own official Homebrew Tap you should use to install the community edition. `$ brew tap mongodb/brew` then install using 
`$ brew install mongodb-community`. As for the services, if you run `$ brew services ` Homebrew now has that Tap included, so no need for doing anything. 
Also, about the startup services, if you just need MongoDB after you log in (as a dev server not a production server), use the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` directory and not the system `/Library/LaunchDeamons` the latter requires root privileges .

Answer (score 152):

Edit: you should now use `brew services start mongodb`, as in Gergo's answer...

When you install/upgrade mongodb, brew will tell you what to do:

> To have launchd start mongodb at login:

```
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

> Then to load mongodb now:

```
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

> Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:

```
    mongod
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: I hadn't seen that instruction! This works perfectly for me on Mac OSX 10.8.4, I think I installed it with Brew. Jacob's comment in the accepted answer pointed to an unknown file when I tried it.

Comment: I prefer this solution over the accepted answer. Copying the plist in the answer above make things a little harder when updating mongo; you'll have to remember to update the paths as needed. Using a symlink as advised by homebrew however takes care of this for you. I used this approach, and the aliases from the answer above (replacing org.mongodb.mongod with homebrew.mxcl.mongodb), and things work great

Comment: I tried this solution and the database I was using "disappeared"! I believe this is the reason: the default plist provided by homebrew stores the mongod configuration at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf. This configuration specifies the dbpath to be /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db. Just wanted to note this in the event it happens to someone else. To get my database to appear again, I had to unload and remove the symbolic link.

Comment: Note: There's some weirdness with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` inside `tmux`

Comment: @ttemple any idea how to undo all these?

Answer (score 75):

Homebrew's [`services`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services) tap integrates formulas with the `launchctl` manager. Adding it is easy:

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

You can then launch MongoDB with this command (this will also start mongodb on boot):

```
brew services start mongodb
```

You can also use `stop` or `restart`:

```
brew services stop mongodb
brew services restart mongodb
```

Comment: Liked the answer but found that brew will remove services in the future. brew services start mongodb
Warning: brew services is unsupported and will be removed soon.

Comment: That's sad news. For now it's just deprecated, which means it will be removed sometime, but it still works. Hopefully someone will volunteer to maintain it as a tap. I will update my answer when it gets removed, or when a tap becomes available.

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew

Comment: It has been removed already, since I see `Error: Unknown command: services` when I tried this way.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer with the new instructions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. @iplus26 it still works for me

Comment: You don't have to use `brew tap homebrew/services` any longer and haven't for quite some time. Think you'll get a deprecation message if you do that now. This tap is called automatically when you list `brew services` the first time.

Answer (score 14):

If you feel like having a simple gui to fix this (as I do), then I can recommend the mongodb pref-pane. Description: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/macosx-preferences-pane-for-mongodb

On github: https://github.com/remysaissy/mongodb-macosx-prefspane

Answer (score 3):

Just installed MongoDB via Homebrew. At the end of the installation console, you can see an output as follows:

To start mongodb:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

So, **brew services start mongodb**, managed to run MongoDB as a service for me.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of looking around on the Mac side.  You may want to use the installer [here](https://github.com/paulrosania/mongo-installer/downloads) as it looks like it does all the setup for you to automatically launch on Mac OS. The only downside is it looks like it's using a pretty old mongo version.

This link [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-x) also explains the setup to get mongo automatically launching as a background service on the Mac.

Comment: Link no longer available.

Comment: not sure if it was the exact same, but fixed link to go to article explaining the same concept

Answer (score 1):

## First Step

install mongodb in your linux machine with

> apt install mongodb-client && apt install mongodb-server

## second step is

change the database path instead of your system default path if you want.

so do the following steps and change it for yourself.

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/data/db --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/log/mongodb.log --logappend --rest
```

and in your windows machine do it just like that just put an --install flag.
you have to get a successful message.

**Best Regards...**

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 10.13.6 with MongoDB 4.0

I was unable to connect to localhost from the mongo shell

I started MongoDB with:

> mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

I found that the 'mongod.conf' had:

> bindIp: 127.0.0.1

Change my JavaScript connection from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** and it worked fine.

The same was occurring with MongoDB Compass too.

Answer (score 0):

`mongod` wasn't working to start the daemon for me but after I ran the following, it started working:

```
'mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log'
```

(from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Answer (score -1):

```
mongod --dbpath [path_to_data_directory]
```

Comment: OP wants to run it as a service, not interactively. A good answer should address this directly.

Answer (score -1):

After installing mongodb through brew, run this to get it up and running:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Comment: This is the same answer @Rejeev-Divakaran provided over five years ago. Please be sure to check existing answers before submitting a new one. If one exists that suggests your same approach, the appropriate action is to upvote it—a privilege you’ll earn after receiving four more reputation points, I believe.