# Cannot connect to mongodb errno:61 Connection refused

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I recently installed mongodb-2.6.0 with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).
After successfully installed, I tried to connect using the `mongo` command. I am receiving the following errors which do not allow me to connect:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused

Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146

exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Are you sure the mongod service is even running? What configuration options do you have on your conf file?

Comment: Did you use sudo apt-get to install? I've read about people experiencing issues with this... try removing and download via the [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) site instead.

Comment: I installed with homebrew, the directions on the official website did not state I need to setup a .config file. I simply downloaded it and ran the 'mongoose' command which resulted in the above errors.

Comment: Check your logs, generally in `/var/logs/mongodb` if I remember correctly.

Comment: I re-installed through the download and unzip'ed the file. I am running 'mongo' and still receiving the same errors.

Comment: Server Fault has a canonical question about [Connection Refused](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message).

Answer (score 280, accepted):

It can happen when the mongodb service is not running on the mac. To start it, I tried

```
brew services start mongodb
```

and it worked.

Edit: According to the discussion on this PR on homebrew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/30628

`brew services` is deprecated, I looked around on SO and found these answers now answer the question: [What is the correct way to start a mongod service on linux / OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596521/what-is-the-correct-way-to-start-a-mongod-service-on-linux-os-x)

Comment: I am getting an error with this command: "Unknown command:services"

Comment: It is also possible this is because in the config file, the IP is bound to 127.0.0.1, and you connect with localhost.

Comment: 'brew services' is no longer supported: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32006

Comment: I tried sudo ***mongod*** instead of mongo and it started! To access mongo shell, I opened new shell window and wrote mongo and it worked!! You can find full error trace with solution [on this blog](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/02/mongodb-correct-way-to-start-error-Cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno-61-connection-refused.html)

Comment: The brew services is no longer supported in my Mac OS X Yosemite. `sudo mongod` started the mongodb and then mongo command worked. Thanks @Ali Raza Bhayani.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!! The brew service command worked for me in my Mac OS X Sierra.

Comment: I would use sudo to start the service.

Answer (score 34):

I encountered the exact same issue and here is a clear step by step process to avoid this error.

**Step 1** - Installation ( Don't follow this step if you have already installed MongoDB ):

```
brew update
brew install mongodb
```

**Step 2** - Run Mongo Daemon:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
sudo mongod
```

**Step 3** - Run Mongo Shell Interface:

```
mongo
```

In this sequence, I was able to run the `mongo` command without any error. I have also detailed the error trace and its solution [on this blog](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/02/mongodb-correct-way-to-start-error-Cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno-61-connection-refused.html).

Comment: This is also referenced on MongoDB official page: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb

Comment: this worked for me once... but then it fell over :/ This seems to have done the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22623543/1177832

Comment: This is a good way to win the battle and lose the war. Don't run services as root.

Answer (score 22):

To solve your issue you need to follow the instructions which are then given to you by brew after you use "brew install mongodb".

To have launchd start mongodb at login:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Then to load mongodb now:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

You may be able to just run that last command, but it didn't work for me and I needed to run the second command. To save me in the future. I just ran the first command too. Hope that helps!

**EDIT** Hrishi's method of using `brew services mongodb start` worked good for me. I think they should include this in the mongo docs.

Comment: I used the last command and visited localhost/27017 in my browser, the screen said, 'It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.' That doesn't not seem to be correct...

Comment: Mongo is now running though right? As in you can type **mongo** in shell and you are no longer getting the connection refused message? You won't be accessing mongo from the browser, you'll want to work with it from the cli.

Comment: No, no command in the shell will execute after I enter 'mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf' It is simple a blank prompt. I re-stalled without using homebrew and download the zip from the website, moved the executables to /usr/local/bin, but now I still receiving the same error messages.

Comment: yeah the last command just hung for me too. I'd just run the first two and you should be good. When it hangs, just hit `ctrl + c` and try `mongo` after that.

Comment: Hmm...It is still not working. I'll will post on the mongoDB forums. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 16):

In another tab, you can start the mongo shell with

> mongod

Then return to the previous tab and try again. If you're having trouble setting up your mongoshell, check out this link on the mongo shell: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/
or this link on installing mongodb:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: This did it for me. I totally overlooked starting the service mongod before trying to run mongo. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue when calling `mongod` from the command line.

I resolved this by calling instead `sudo mongod`.

Comment: Don't run services as root.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is here looking for the answer for this after your mac has updated to OS Catalina

run

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

find more info here: https://medium.com/@semmons245/arghhhh-thanks-to-the-catalina-os-update-this-now-needs-changing-987f416ebcbe

Answer (score 4):

for me on osx, I had to kill old running instance, then restarting worked.

```
$>ps -aef | grep mongo
502  8047     1   0 11:52AM ??         0:00.23 /usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf 

$>sudo kill 8047

$>sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error but a different root cause. Thought I'd post the solution here in case anyone else runs into the problem. I got this error after my Mac improperly shut down while I was running `mongorestore -d foo dump/foo/`.

**tl;dr**: I fixed the problem by removing the damaged `foo.ns` file along with `foo.0`, `foo.1`,... from my data folder `/usr/local/var/mongodb/`. Then I restarted the mongo server with `brew services restart mongodb` and I was back to normal.

**Details**: I kept getting the error even after trying to start or restart the mongodb service via brew or launchctl. Eventually I ran

`mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb`

and saw that the service was not actually starting, and the start sequence included the following error:

`[initandlisten] bad .ns file: /usr/local/var/mongodb/foo.ns
[initandlisten] User Assertion: 10079:bad .ns file length, cannot open database`

I got rid of the bad `.ns` file and the rest of the data files, and the next time I started the service I was good to go.

Comment: My only regret is I only have one upvote to give: all the other answers ignore the fact that the default brew configs put dbs in /usr/local/var/mongodb !

Comment: Annnddd Mongo just crashed again, so now I had to go through this process again. Good thing I upvoted your answer so I could find it again :D

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after I upgraded to mongo 3.6 with homebrew.

The log `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` contained the message `shutting down with code:62`. This error code means that the existing database is too old to run with the current version of mongo.

I found 2 solutions in another  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47850004/490592):

- Delete your database folder (`/usr/local/var/mongodb`)
- Or follow the [upgrade procedure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/)

I chose to upgrade. In my case, that meant I had to downgrade to 3.4, run a command in the mongo console, then upgrade again. Mongo requires you to upgrade one major version at a time, so depending on how far back you were, there could be additional steps. The docs will guide you.

The `brew switch` [*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987683/490592) and `brew services restart` commands made swapping between versions relatively painless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed MongoDB then first try to run mongod as a sudo user, I was facing the issue because of not running mongod as a superuser.

I have pasted the o/p for both the commands(**mongod** and **sudo mongod**) at very bottom, you can check that too but

**First try this**

```
sudo mongod
```

**not this**

```
mongod
```

I had installed MongoDB on my MAC OS X Sierra 10.12.6 by by running the following command in sequence.

```
brew update
brew install mongodb --devel
brew services start mongodb
```

then created a directory to which mongod process will write the data, this is optional as mongod process takes it by default, see this useful guide at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Finally started **mongod** process as follows

```
sudo mongod
```

Oputput of ***mongod*** (failed) and ***sudo mongod*** (succeeded) commands on my terminal.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:appscheck admin$ mongod
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2698 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-2.local
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-12-10T08:12:06.166+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-12-10T08:12:06.167+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-12-10T08:12:06.167+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100


MacBook-Pro-2:appscheck admin$ sudo mongod
Password:
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2700 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-2.local
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-10T08:12:14.084+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2017-12-10T08:12:14.560+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-12-10T08:12:14.707+0530 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2017-12-10T08:12:14.707+0530 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2017-12-10T08:12:14.719+0530 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2017-12-10T08:12:14.720+0530 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2017-12-10T08:12:14.720+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Then I opened new terminal to start querying the **MongoDB**, it worked.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:appscheck admin$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-10T08:12:14.472+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> show dbs;
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
> use practice
switched to db practice
>
```

**That's it.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in looking in the log file I saw this:

```
{2019-03-09T11:57:32.136-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: 
Data directory /usr/local/var/mongodb not found., terminating}
```

so I created the directory `/usr/local/var/mongodb`
issued the brew services restart mongodb command I was able to open the mongo console.

Answer (score -1):

> My guess is that you do not have a running database while trying to access testing through the "mongo" command.
>
> First run this command in terminal:

```
mongod
```

> Then open another terminal window and run:

mongo

> Everything should be working now.

Answer (score -1):

My similar error is resolved by deleting "sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock" file while trying to run mongod.
Now u can run mongod and then mongo.