# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

while trying this mongo command in ubuntu
I am getting this error.

```
    ritzysystem@ritzysystem-Satellite-L55-A:~$ mongo
    MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
    connecting to: test
    2014-10-06T12:59:35.802+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
    2014-10-06T12:59:35.802+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
    exception: connect failed
```

how can I rectify this is anyone had the same problem.

Comment: `mongod` server is not running, turn it up by typing `mongod` on terminal.

Comment: Your mongod is not running on 127.0.0.1 Can you try like this "mongo --host localhost"

Comment: thank you everyone I tried running mongo it was not running finally I found there was no space in my hard disc I emptied some of the space and finally re installed it the same installation procedure as followed to install as given in mongodb docs finally restarted the server and it is running. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: you can answer your own question (rather than post a comment). The solution would be more visible and it will help others

Comment: is IP address appear here (VPS available IPs):
`ifconfig -a | grep "inet"`
is IP listened by mongo?
`sudo lsof -i | grep mongo`
If not, there is system corruption because even you define your mongod.conf file, it won't be listening your defined values. Also make sure to allow mongo and port for firewall to pass `sudo ufw allow yourport` and `sudo ufw app list` to see if it's allowed app among others

Comment: Maybe it's not required mongodb app to be listed as an app because it uses ports

Answer (score 22, accepted):

thank you everyone I tried running mongo it was not running finally I found there was no space in my hard disc I emptied some of the space and finally re installed it the same installation procedure as followed to install as given in mongodb docs finally restarted the server and it is running.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu

Comment: I don't know why you are reinstalled. I think its enough to free some space by deleting unwanted files and then you might want to restart mongod service, because the mongod service might be killed due to no space. is there any specific reason to reinstall?.

Answer (score 101):

Run the following command :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
```

[Connection refused to MongoDB errno 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899849/connection-refused-to-mongodb-errno-111)

**MacOS:**

```
rm /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock  
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: on Ubuntu: mongod instead of mongodb

Comment: After running sudo service mongod restart on Ubuntu: `Job for mongod.service failed. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: there is no `mongodb` in `/var/lib/`

Comment: run ```mongod``` instead

Comment: Run perfect on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem on Mac OS
Try to run **sudo mongod** and in a new terminal tab run **mongo**

Comment: I had to run `mongo` with sudo also

Answer (score 19):

In my case the error was due to missing /data/db folder which the mongodb uses to store your  data. Please type this command `$sudo mongod`  in your terminal. If the error message is something like :

**`missing data/db folder error`**

Simply create the folder and you are good to go.

Comment: Weird how it's not created automatically.

Comment: create directroy data/db in the root folder, now working fine.

Comment: Note: don't forget to also grant permissions to the folder. `mkdir /data/db` then `chmod 777 /data/db`

Answer (score 11):

First,
**Start MongoDB:**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Then, **Run:**

```
mongo
```

Answer (score 9):

Probably you don't have space in your hard drive.
Check it by typing in the promt   `df -h`

Please note that mongo might fail even with 3gb available in the corresponding partition. For details, you might want to check the log: `cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: "mongodb.log" had a typo and is written as "mongod.log". I tried to edit but stackoverflow told me I had to edit at least 6 chars. Bad idea imo SO.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have run the MongoDB's Service before you want to connect the console.

run and start the server:

```
$ sudo mongod
```

then:

```
$ mongo
...
>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on my Mac, and I installed mongodb via homebrew. I solve this problem by the *homebrew services* command.

#### First start mongodb service:

`$ brew services start mongodb`

#### Start mongodb terminal

`$ mongo`

#### Stop mongodb service:

`$ brew services stop mongodb`

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
```

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04 which you can figure out by runnign this:

```
lsb_release -a
```

You need to Create a new file at `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was caused due to an apparent lost of permission over mongodb.lock file. I could solve the problem changing the permission with the  following command :

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.lock
```

There follows my investigation:
[image: step-by-step verification]

Answer (score 4):

I think except for disk space issuse, you should check the log in `/var/log/mongodb` to know the details for why mongodb start failed.

```
cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

2016-06-26T15:26:26.642+0800 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8130 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=hadoop-master
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-06-26T15:26:26.649+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.3.10", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-06-26T15:26:26.678+0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-06-26T15:26:26.678+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-06-26T15:26:26.678+0800 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

So, here I need to rm all the files in the `/tmp`. That works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

For mongo v3.6.3+ (or 2019 versions)

```
rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand the question is with regards to Ubuntu.

But if you're getting the same error on a Mac and don't want `$ sudo mongod` running on a separate tab, you can do the following to fix the connection error, if you have Homebrew -

```
brew services start mongodb
```

Based on the answer from this thread - [Cannot connect to mongodb errno:61 Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418134/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno61-connection-refused)

Answer (score 3):

In my case bind_ip was not 127.0.0.1 in */etc/mongodb.conf* file so change bind_ip to 127.0.0.1(it may be comma separated values so make sure 127.0.0.1 is one of them) Then **restart** your system to take effect.
Restart only to the those who are facing

```
$sudo service mongod restart
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this simple steps; (Works on MAC OS too)

1. Open terminal and run `sudo mongod`
2. Open a new terminal tab(Don't close step 1 tab) and run `sudo mongo`

That's all

Answer (score 1):

is very simple, only delete a file `/var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.lock`. after only execute: `mongo`. finished

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the data directory for mongo specified in `/etc/mongod.conf` is not a valid path.

Try rechecking the path if it really exists `sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf` and check `dbPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts on my case.

If you have changed the dbPath and logPath dirs to your custom values (say /data/mongodb/data, /data/mongodb/log), you must chown them to mongodb user, otherwise, the non-existent /data/db/ dir will be used.

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/mongodb/

sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error with you, this is my case:

```
~# mongod
2018-07-15T05:27:08.265+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2018-07-15T05:27:08.265+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2018-07-15T05:27:08.301+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2018-07-15T05:27:08.301+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=26796 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-sfo2-01
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.6
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1ef45a23a4c5e3480ac919b28afcba3c615488f2
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux build6.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-15T05:27:08.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-07-15T05:27:08.308+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I type mongod to start the server, and I type `control` + `c` to exit to shell

then I type `mongo` and I got

```
~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2018-07-15T05:05:02.738+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2018-07-15T05:05:02.739+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
```

As you can see, my error info is same with you.

This is case mongod doesn't start with backend process, when I type `control` + `c` I quit mongod.

We can add --fork args to make the process daemon process.

```
#  mongod --logpath /usr/local/mongodb/log.txt --fork
```

you have to set --logpath if you want to use --fork

then you will success to connect to mongo

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, so please check is there mongodb folder, firstly try to remove that folder

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*
```

Now try to start mongo and if same problem then its mongodb lock file which prevent to start mongo, so please delete the mongo lock file

```
rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

For forcefully `rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

service mongodb restart if already in sudo mode
otherwise you need to use like `sudo service mongod start`

or you can start the server using fork method

```
mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

and for watching the same is it forked please check using the below command

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo 3.*.* - OSX - 2017**

*From README*

```
RUNNING
```

Change directory to mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.*.*/bin

To run a single server database:

```
$ mkdir /data/db
$ ./mongod
```

Go to new **Terminal**

```
$ # The mongo javascript shell connects to localhost and test database 
$ # by default -Run the following command in new terminal
$ ./mongo 
> help
```

Comment: Why the downvoting? this is the way you should do it??!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved that simply by entering `sudo mongo` after `mongod` command.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed mongo following the instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ And then I installed again following the instructions in the given link. Everything worked smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

There are changes in **mongod.conf** file in the latest MongoDB v 3.6.5 +

Here is how I fixed this issue on mac os High Sierra v 10.12.3

Note: I assume that you have installed/upgrade MongoDB using homebrew

> mongo --version

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5 
git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618 
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018 
allocator: system modules: none build environment:
distarch: x86_64
target_arch: x86_64
```

1. find **mongod.conf** file

   ```
    sudo find / -name mongod.conf`
   ```

   > /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf > first result .
2. open **mongod.conf** file

   ```
   sudo vi /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
   ```
3. edit in the file for remote access under *net:* section

   ```
    port: 27017  
    bindIpAll: true 
    #bindIp: 127.0.0.1 // comment this out
   ```
4. restart mongodb

   if you have installed using brew than

   ```
   brew services stop mongodb

   brew services start mongodb
   ```

otherwise, kill the process.

```
   sudo kill -9 <procssID>
```

Comment: To people reading this answer: CAREFUL! Unless I'm mistaken, commenting out `bindIp` will expose your databases to the open internet unless you've got authorization enabled (it isn't enabled by default).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the connection to the database, it could be due to several reasons.
For me it was low disk space on my server machine, and when mongo tries to connect it refuse because of low disk, check your server machine local storage with `du -sh` if you have low storage space, check your logs size and take step accordingly, issue may exist because of dbpath contradict in `/etc/mongod.conf` and server actually running dbpath with `mongod`
If you are facing such type of issue, please check my answer in the given link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057695/8247133

Answer (score 0):

For those with Windows. I had the same problem on Windows.
Restarting Mongodb service solves this.

Following are the steps to restart on Windows:

i). Go To "Services" on Windows.

ii). Search for "MongoDB" in the list of services.

iii). Right click "start"/"restart" depending on your status.

iv). After the status turns to "running" check if issue is resolved by running "Mongo" or connecting your Mongo client.

Answer (score 0):

For `macOS` many of the answers are already outdated according to [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). Somehow the `brew` has changed and how we should install `MongoDB`, firstly uninstall it from your `macOS` (even though it might be not necessary) and then install it using these steps:

1. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew install mongodb-community@4.4`
3. `brew services start mongodb-community@4.4`

Watch out for the `4.4` part, it'll change. If in the future it would break then refer to the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) and install the version, which is suggested in the linked tutorial.