# mongo exception: connect failed on a fresh install

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, debian, rocket.chat

I've installed mongodb for the very first time on my Debian 8, following this [mongodb install guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/). The goal is to use mongodb for rocket.chat, for which I follow [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-rocket-chat-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

So far, all I did was:

```
$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
$echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install mongodb-org

$sudo systemctl enable mongod
$sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
<insert>    
replication:                                                               
   oplogSizeMB: 1                                                          
   replSetName: rs0

$sudo systemctl restart mongod
$export LC_ALL=C
$sudo mongo

MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2016-12-14T10:21:55.356+0100 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2016-12-14T10:21:55.356+0100 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I'm monitoring the log file, when attempting to access the mongo shell, but nothing shows up.

The `mongod` service is running, configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 and I'm working on the server locally.

How do I access the mongo shell from the localhost?

**edit** Solved. The issue was an iptables rule, that disallowed local connections to the mongodb.

Comment: Try deleting /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock file and restart service. Then try connecting.

Comment: The connection fails with the same error message after deleting the lock and restarting the service.

Comment: Strange! Just to test, stop the service and run mongodb manually and then try to connect using 'mongo'. You can simply run  'mkdir -p /data/db && chown -R $USER:$USER /data/db && mongod'.  After this open another shell and run 'mongo'. If this works then most probably, it has some permission problem.

Comment: fails with the same error again.

Comment: Do you have any firewall in place? Run 'iptables -L'

Comment: This is a good point. Thanks for the hint - I'll check it out soon!

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
```

Credit: [Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211671/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno111-connection-refused/27290807#27290807)

Comment: I should have edited my post, I've resolved the issue. My firewall was blocking the local connection. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score -1):

You can access the mongodb shell by changing directory to your MongoDb installation and entering ./bin/mongo. See this guide: [enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: The issue is that the connection to the shell isn't working. If I'm not mistaken, the link plainly suggests changing into the directory of the mongo executable and starting it. Which I do (as shown in OP) and fails to connect.

Comment: Is the mongod daemon running?. What is the output of the command: "service mongod status"

Comment: Yes, it's running - `active (running)`

Comment: Does the mongodb service show when you enter the netstat command?. You can check with this command: netstat -tulpn

Comment: Yes it does, as another user suggested, I need to check the firewall rules.

Answer (score -1):

To recover from an unclean shutdown run these in a terminal

```
killall mongod
cd ~
./mongod --repair
rm -rfv data/mongod.lock
./mongod
```

If you want to remove the `--httpinterface warning then run`, try this :

```
echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest --httpinterface "$@"' > mongod
```

(it only needs running once) before you run

```
./mongod
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!