# Getting `TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new' even though Discord.py is on 1.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I'm trying to deploy a python bot to Discord via the heroku server, however I keep getting the `TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'` error when trying to deploy. Here are my full Heroku logs:

```
2020-08-16T20:25:13.659787+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-16T20:25:16.913818+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python3 bot.py`
2020-08-16T20:25:17.587024+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-16T20:25:19.550960+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-16T20:25:19.550974+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 340, in <module>
2020-08-16T20:25:19.551390+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot.run(CONFIG['bot_token'])
2020-08-16T20:25:19.551394+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
2020-08-16T20:25:19.551800+00:00 app[worker.1]: return future.result()
2020-08-16T20:25:19.551801+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552173+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552174+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 585, in start
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552515+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552535+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 499, in connect
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552848+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self._connect()
2020-08-16T20:25:19.552851+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 463, in _connect
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553175+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self.ws.poll_event()
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553178+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553485+00:00 app[worker.1]: await self.received_message(msg)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553509+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553801+00:00 app[worker.1]: func(data)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.553802+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554217+00:00 app[worker.1]: guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554239+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554648+00:00 app[worker.1]: guild._from_data(data)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554649+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 296, in _from_data
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554889+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._sync(guild)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.554892+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 323, in _sync
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555147+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._add_channel(TextChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555186+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 107, in __init__
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555394+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._update(guild, data)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555394+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 131, in _update
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555575+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._fill_overwrites(data)
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555575+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555815+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
2020-08-16T20:25:19.555864+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
2020-08-16T20:25:19.754714+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-16T20:25:19.797906+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-08-16T20:25:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

I've been looking around for fixes, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've upgraded my discord.py library to 1.4.1, as well as added an alias, still nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the version on `requirments.txt`. so that it can rebuild correctly.

Also try and get the version on Heroku to double check it.

```
discord.py==1.4.1
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I'm able to get in online now, however I run into this error:
 `ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`. 

I'm running mongo on that port so I don't get what's going on here. I also tried deleted the mongod.lock file in /data/db and restarting mongo, however still the same thing. Any clue?

Comment: I don't use mongodb but since deleting and restarting did not work [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33661753/13975447).