# MongoDB - shutting down with code:62

Tags: mongodb

I followed the MongoDB Docs to run my MongoDB in macOS,

When I start MongoDB using the terminal get this error:

> Shutting down with code: 62

[image]

Comment: I got the same error running mongodb in docker on an ec2 instance.
Fixed it by deleting the data directory where mongodb stored its metadata and documents.

For me it was located at /data/db

Comment: it worked for me too. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note to future viewers of this question: You may have gotten this error after updating MongoDB. If so you should look at upgrading your previously stored information if you're worried about losing it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Delete the data directory where MongoDB stored and create again.

```
rmdir data
```

And:

```
mkdir data/db
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It helped me to fix the issue :)

Comment: what is resaon for that can u please say

Comment: what if I wanna keep the data?

Comment: If you aren't interested in deleting your database, you can [easily upgrade it](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv). This really shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: In my case, remove data dir @ /var/lib/mongodb and make a new empty directory /var/lib/mongodb with 777 permission.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem when I switched to a new version `mongod` without upgrading the data (from version `3.2`, for example, to version `3.6`).

In this case, `mongod` outputs `** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.` (`mongod` was started with the `--verbose` key).

[The link](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv) does lead to detailed instructions on how to upgrade the data.

It is strange that error `62` is not described in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/).

Comment: The short version of how to go from 3.2 to 3.6 is to install 3.4 first, then run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )`. After that I could upgrade to 3.6 successfully.

Comment: Now the exit code `62` appeared in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/).

Comment: @ChadvonNau after upgrading did you face any issues in the 3.6 version?

Comment: @Jerry No, I did not. I only have one small database for a http://keystonejs.com app, so I can't speak for anything beyond that.

Answer (score 9):

This has worked for me

Initially i was facing various issues, like when i tried to start the server by using:

```
mongod
```

[I received this error: shutting down with code 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBQ8X.png)

and then i tried to start by

```
sudo mongod
```

[I received this error: shutting down with code 62](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vKpj.png)

finally this command helped me to get rid of various issues

```
sudo mongod --repair
```

Now mongod server is running tentatively

```
sudo mongod
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. I had to use the right mongo version for the database, and then `--repair`. After that, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Error code 62:MongoDB dbpath doesn't support the current version
```

Removing data director is not an `optimal` solution. The best solution would be to **[upgrade](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/)** to the higher version.

Else take the **dump & restore** the complete database on a fresh instance with a higher version.

> mongodump --db employee --out /path/
>
> mongorestore /path/employee/

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Mongodbump doesn't work once you've seen error code 62, because the server CANNOT start

Comment: mongodump and restore is not an option if you have a lot of data and if it has to happen fast.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue on Arch Linux. I solved it by installing mongodb34-bin from the AUR (which required removing the mongodb package). Then I ran

```
$ sudo mongodb --repair
```

Then, I started the database from the 3.4 binary, and ran

```
$ mongo
> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
> quit
```

After that, I stopped the 3.4 version, and reinstalled the regular mongodb package, and did a second repair.

Comment: Clarify whether MongoDB 3.4 was newer or older than the other mongodb package.

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure if you are upgrading MongoDB, your featureCompatibilityVersion version is correct. I faced similar problem, after updating featureCompatibilityVersion to the correct version, it worked fine.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, this error seems to come due to skipping one or more versions when upgrading MongoDB. The proper solution (i.e., no data loss) is to go through the versions one at a time.

For each version, make sure to run the `mongo` shell for that version, and run the following command:

```js
db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion:"<major.minor>"})
```

...where `<major.minor>` is replaced with the major and minor version of MongoDB. For example, version 4.4.9 would become `4.4`, and version 5.0.2 would become `5.0`.

Eventually the new version of MongoDB that you are trying to run should succeed.

NOTE: if you step through the versions without the admin command, it probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change back the binaries to Mongodb 3.4.2.3 to follow:
Download tar from mongodb website as per your destribution from : https://www.mongodb.org/downloads Untar downloaded file.

```
tar -zxvf {mongo-tar-file}.tgz
```

Stop mongod service.

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Replace binaries from your tar/bin to /usr/bin.

```
cd {your-extracted-folder}/bin

sudo mv -f * /usr/bin/
```

Start mongod service.

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and then when mongo running

```
again do: db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

Then you can update to 3.6

Comment: please format your commands into code blocks so they'd become more readable

Answer (score 1):

Answers of others are correct but not work for me and i fix this problem like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongo*
```

Or you can use:

```
sudo apt remove mongo*
```

After that:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

and:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc \
  sudo apt-key add -
```

then:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

after that:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.2.0 \
                        mongodb-org-server=4.2.0 \
                        mongodb-org-shell=4.2.0 \
                        mongodb-org-mongos=4.2.0 \
                        mongodb-org-tools=4.2.0
```

Finally:

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

My errror started with an error 62.

`2018-06-10T13:49:27.750-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62`

I deleted /db and reinstalled /db in /data/db.

`$ sudo -r rm db`

Once I did this and tried to run >mongod I got a 100 error.  I had to change the rights

`2018-06-10T13:52:20.042-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100`

To fix this I did:

`` $ sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db ``

Once this was run I was able to run mongo db.

`$mongod`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your directory **C:**, you may see the folder "**data**", and do:

```
mkdir -p data\db
```

in your command prompt in that location.

Answer (score -1):

Although the accepted answer works, it removes *all* your data.

What worked for me without need to lose my DB is using `mongodump` to create a backup of the data. Then removing it by `sudo rm -r /path/to/dbdata` and finally restoring it with `mongorestore`.

That made `systemctl start mongodb` to not fail and the data was in perfect state.

Comment: Mongodump doesn't work if the server won't start ;)