# How to upgrade mongo server version?

Tags: mongodb

I have ugraded my mongo database from 2.6 to 3.6
But when  run mongo I have this warning

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 2.6.2
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
```

How to upgrade server version to be v3.6.4
When i google for a result, i always return to pages of installation that i have executed the commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I restart and now i have this error in the logs
shutting down with code:62
according to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62] ishould delete the folder /data/db, but it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You will have to restart your `mongod` process.

You have some options to use;

Use `--shutdown`

From the Linux command line, shut down the mongod using the --shutdown option in the following command:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

Use `kill`

From the Linux command line, shut down a specific mongod instance using one of the following commands:

```
kill <mongod process ID>
kill -2 <mongod process ID>
```

I hope this helps.

Source: [Manage mongod Processes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Comment: I restart the process and i have this error in the log :
shutting down with code:62
i tried this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62] but it didn't help
NB : i have upgraded from 2.6 to 3.6

Comment: have you tried upgrading your data?

Comment: I deleted /data/db and when i try to backup my data with : mongorestore -d db_name path/, it returns : 
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Comment: even mongod --repair returns : shutting down with code:100