# MongoDB - when start the mongodb its shutting down with code:62

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I followed the MongoDB Docs to run my MongoDB in ubuntu 18.04,

When I start MongoDB using "sudo mongod --dbpath /home/ubuntu/appdb --logpath /home/ubuntu/appdb/mongodb.log --fork" the terminal get this error:

Shutting down with code: 62[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfzP4.png)

Comment: May this thread will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62

Comment: Don't forget the mkdir data/db directory and to make the log directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - shutting down with code:62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62)

Answer (score -1):

Delete directory

```
rmdir data
```

And Create New:

```
mkdir data/db
```

Comment: So you lose all your data? Poor solution.