# Mongod upgrade error after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I get the error message:

> IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded
>   to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.

The problem is that when I run `mongod --version`, it says I'm running 3.6.3.  I'm pretty sure I was already running 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I think I essentially confirmed this by dumping to my laptop and connecting (running 3.6.9 on my laptop), however, I still get the error in Ubuntu.

I tried running `mongod --repair` but still get the error.

I saw this post.  I did back up my data but don't love the idea of having to remove the data directory:

[MongoDB - shutting down with code:62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62)

Comment: Probably Ubuntu 18 uses mongo 3.8 or smth higher than 3.6. Thus, this >= 3.8 only can work with 3.6 storage model then you **must** migrate to at least 3.6, while your 3.6 could work with the model of 3.4.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that you haven't set the feature compatibility version flag to finish upgrading to 3.4. This seems to be a requirement before upgrading to 3.6. What is the output when you run `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )`?