# Unable to connect to my mongodb server on local host

Tags: mongodb

When I enter the command to connect 'mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017' I don't know why I am getting this error, it used to work before. Following the M103 Tutorial on MongoDB University

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.16
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-01-26T17:51:23.154+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-01-26T17:51:23.155+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to mongodb errno:61 Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418134/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno61-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your mongdb service is running or not. 
If yes then can you restart the service and try again. Use below command to restart the service

```
service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication via Kerberos is supported only in (liable to pay costs) MongoDB Enterprise edition, do you use that one?

Check whether mongod service is started.

Comment: yes the mongod service is started yet I am getting same error for using just mongo or even with adding username and password along with it

Answer (score 0):

just try:
mongo

because 27017 is the default

are you sure your mongod is running? if the machine has rebooted then mongod must be relaunched

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message because mongo could not access my database data path.

Mongo log showed this error:

```
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /my_unrecognized_path/data/db not found., terminating
```

Hope this helps.