# MongoDB start error

Tags: mongodb, shell

I have problem to run Mongodb on my OSX. I have installed with brew and when I'm trying to start Mongodb server and type mongo and then run it getting me error:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
2015-11-17T12:56:16.793+0100 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-11-17T12:56:16.794+0100 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Can you please give me some useful advices?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is my useful advice: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-on-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to start a mongod service on linux / OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596521/what-is-the-correct-way-to-start-a-mongod-service-on-linux-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`mongo`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) is the client shell, it's not a server. You start a MongoDB server with the [**`mongod`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/) command. For example:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb/data
```

You can also start `mongod` automatically when your OS starts up. You can find instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061202/236660

After the server is started, you can use `mongo` to connect to the server.

Note that you can also run the mongo shell without connecting to any server:

```
mongo --nodb
```

Of course, you won't be able to do much with just the shell.