# How to stop mongo DB in one command

Tags: mongodb

I need to be able to start/stop MongoDB on the cli. It is quite simple to start:

> ./mongod

But to stop mongo DB, I need to run open mongo shell first and then type two commands:

> $ ./mongo
>
> use admin
>
> db.shutdownServer()

So I don't know how to stop mongo DB in one line. Any help?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

[Starting and Stopping MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) is covered in the MongoDB manual. It explains the various options of stopping MongoDB through the shell, cli, drivers etc. It also details the risks of incorrectly stopping MongoDB (such as data corruption) and talks about the different kill signals.

Additionally, if you have installed MongoDB using a package manager for [Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) or [Debian](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) then you can stop mongodb (currently mongod in ubuntu) as follows:

- Upstart: `sudo service mongod stop`
- Sysvinit: `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop`

Or on [Mac OS X](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

- Find PID of mongod process using `$ top`
- Kill the process by `$ kill <PID>` ([the Mongo docs have more info on this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill))

Or on [Red Hat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) based systems:

- `service mongod stop`

Or on [Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service) if you have installed as a service named `MongoDB`:

- `net stop MongoDB`

And if not installed as a service (as of Windows 7+) you can run:

- `taskkill /f /im mongod.exe`

To learn more about the problems of an unclean shutdown, how to best avoid such a scenario and what to do in the event of an unclean shutdown, please see: [Recover Data after an Unexpected Shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/).

Comment: I believe the order for service is `sudo service mongodb [start|stop|restart|status]`. `sudo service stop mongodb` results in: _stop: unrecognized service_

Comment: @Jacob - We just tried this on ubuntu, you're right, I've edited the answer.

Comment: For Mac, you can also just do 'killall mongod'.  That way, you don't need to know the PID.

Comment: One additional warning might help: If you started `mongod` in the foreground, do *NOT* use CTRL-C to shut it down, since this may lead to lost data.

Comment: Or on Mac: 'ps -ax | grep mongod', then kill the process number

Comment: @Mark When I use the 'net stop MongoDB' on windows it is showing "System Error 1067 has occured"

Comment: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>net start MongoDB

The MongoDB service was started successfully.

Comment: In the new Ubuntu 18.04, I am able to stop it using > sudo service mongod stop ... not "mongodb"

Comment: Note that on my system the service is named mongod. not mongodb. rhel.

Comment: For Mac OSX, the given link is not to-the-point.
Please refer the below link for clear straight forward instructions:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes

Answer (score 118):

If you literally want a one line equivalent to the commands in your original question, you could alias:

`mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"`

Mark's answer on starting and stopping MongoDB via services is the more typical (and recommended) administrative approach.

Comment: Great answer. When setting up multiple instances on development machine (trying the replication set before deployment) it helps to have a .bat 
`start C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config C:\net2\primary1-pc\mongod.cfg 
start C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config C:\net2\secondary1-pc\mongod.cfg
...`

and then have shutdown.bat 
`C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()" --port 27017 
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()" --port 27018
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()" --port 27019
...`

Comment: On Windows where it's installed as a service, I found that `net stop MongoDB` wasn't reliable, so I used something similar: `mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"` .  Cheers!

Comment: @Stennie When I use the 'net stop MongoDB' on windows it is showing "System Error 1067 has occured"

Answer (score 58):

`mongod --dbpath /path/to/your/db --shutdown`

More info at official: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: I love using this way, it works without dbpath too, makes sense if you only have one instance running.

Comment: it seems it is not working for newer versions, from 2.4.xx to latest.

Comment: This is the only answer that I've seen that actually worked.

Comment: macOS 10.12, `mongod v3.4.10`: `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--shutdown'`:-(

Comment: Is there a defined behavior for this if it is run on a primary of a replica set? It seems to behave like `db.shutdownServer({force:1,timeoutSecs:0})` which would inhibit the flushing of remaining data to the secondaries. You might not always want that.

Answer (score 41):

If the server is running as the foreground process in a terminal, this can be done by pressing

```
Ctrl-C
```

Another way to cleanly shut down a running server is to use the shutdown command,

```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer();
```

Otherwise, a command like kill can be used to send
the signal. If mongod has 10014 as its PID, the command would be

```
kill -2 10014
```

Comment: Using kill isn't a good idea, this might lead to a broken DB, which needs a repair for restart. "Never use kill -9 (i.e. SIGKILL) to terminate a mongod instance." Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill

Comment: @JensA.Koch Ya, Nanhe wasn't telling anyone to use a -9 signal, so.. saying "using kill isn't a good idea" simply isn't accurate. Only instant termination is unsafe - a normal kill is perfectly safe and the documentation you linked to advocates it.

Answer (score 25):

I followed the official [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes) for stopping with signals. One of the following commands can be used (PID represents the `Process ID` of the `mongod` process):

```
kill PID
```

which sends signal 15 (SIGTERM), or

```
kill -2 PID
```

which sends signal 2 (SIGINT).

> **Warning from [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes):
>
> Never use `kill -9` (i.e. SIGKILL) to terminate a `mongod` instance.**

If you have more than one instance running or you don't care about the PID, you could use `pkill` to send the signal to all running `mongod` processes:

```
pkill mongod
```

or

```
pkill -2 mongod
```

or, much more safer, only to the processes belonging to you:

```
pkill -U $USER mongod
```

or

```
pkill -2 -U $USER mongod
```

NOTE:
If the DB is running as another user, but you have administrative rights, you have invoke the above commands with `sudo`, in order to run them. E.g.:

```
sudo pkill mongod
sudo pkill -2 mongod
```

## PS

Note: I resorted to using signals because `mongod --shutdown`, although mentioned in the current [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes), did not work on my machine (macOS, mongodb v3.4.10, installed with `homebrew`):

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--shutdown'
```

### Update 2022-05-10

meanwhile option `--shutdown` is marked in the documentation as "`Supported on Linux only`".

## PPS

(macOS specific) Before anyone wonders: no, I could not stop it with command

```
brew services stop mongodb
```

because I did not start it with

```
brew services start mongodb
```

I had started `mongod` with a custom command line :-)

Comment: Great answer, which confirmed that MongoDB can be gracefully terminated using SIGTERM signal. It is important if running MongoDB in a Docker - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#stop_grace_period . Additional note that CMD ["mongod", "option", "option" ] needs to be used to make sure that MongoDB gets PID 1, then signal sent by Docker will reach your DB.

Answer (score 11):

Use `mongod --shutdown`

According to the official doc : [manage-mongodb-processes/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

:D

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Failed to kill process: errno:1 Operation not permitted.

Comment: Only for Linux: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-shutdown

Comment: This what only worked for me. I don't have mongod as service and the start command was showing error is an instance of mongod is already running. Thanks a ton, man!

Answer (score 8):

create a file called mongostop.bat

save the following code in it

```
 mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"
```

run the file mongostop.bat and you successfully have mongo stopped

Answer (score 8):

My special case is:

previously start mongod by:

```
sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

now, want to stop `mongod`.

and refer official doc [Stop mongod Processes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes), has tried:

(1) `shutdownServer` but failed:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.shutdownServer()
2019-03-06T14:13:15.334+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: shutdownServer failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "shutdown must run from localhost when running db without auth",
        "code" : 13
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.shutdownServer@src/mongo/shell/db.js:302:1
@(shell):1:1
```

(2) `--shutdown` still failed:

```
# mongod --shutdown
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

(3) previous start command adding --shutdown:

```
sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --shutdown
killing process with pid: 30213
failed to kill process: errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

(4) use `service` to stop:

```
service mongod stop
```

and

```
service mongod status
```

show expected `Active: inactive (dead)` but `mongod` actually **still** running, for can see process from ps:

```
# ps -edaf | grep mongo | grep -v grep
root     30213     1  0 Feb04 ?        03:33:22 mongod --port PORT --dbpath=/var/lib/mongo
```

and **finally**, really stop mongod by:

```
# sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --shutdown
killing process with pid: 30213
```

until now, root cause: still unknown ...

hope above solution is useful for your.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer from stennie:

```
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer();quit()"
```

I found that mongo was trying to reconnect to the db after the server shut down, which would cause a delay and error messages.  Adding quit() after shutdown speeds it up and reduces the messages, but there is still one.

I also want to add context - I'm starting and stopping mongod as part of test cases for other code, so registering as a service does not fit the use case.  I am hoping to end up with something that runs on all platforms (this tested in windows right now).  I'm using mongod 3.6.9

Comment: I really liked this version. I didnt know the service/ execulable or pid.. or none of them returned expected response. this helped me.

Answer (score 5):

One liners to start or stop mongodb service using command line;

1. To start the service use: `NET START MONGODB`
2. To stop the service use: `NET STOP MONGODB`

I use this myself, it does work.

Comment: I get this on using those commands on windows:  c:\mongodb\bin>NET START MONGODB
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.


c:\mongodb\bin>NET STOP MONGODB
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

Comment: On windows you first have to install mongodb as a service using the --install option.  The commands you can use a command similar to the following to install it as a service.

mongod --install --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\data --logpath C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\log\mongodb.log --logappend --rest

The command above must be run with administrator privileges.  After that is done you can then use the net start and net stop commands provided by Hugo.

Answer (score 3):

From the given commands I think you're on Linux.

**Start MongoDB:**

```
$ sudo service mongod start
mongod start/running, process XXXXX
```

**Check the Status:**

```
$ sudo service mongod status
mongod start/running, process XXXXX
```

**Stop MongoDB:**

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
mongod stop/waiting
```

Answer (score 3):

Using homebrew (recommended way):

To start:

**`brew services start mongodb-community`**

To stop:

**`brew services stop mongodb-community`**

Answer (score 1):

I simply did:

`quit();`

Please note I'm using mongo 3.0.

[Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/quit/)

Comment: If you were running in a VM, that command would just stop the VM.

Answer (score 1):

in the terminal window on your mac, press control+c

Comment: Someone downvoted this. It is, in fact, one of the ways to stop mongo according with mongo documentation. In a majority of situations this will not work, as mongo should be running in that terminal and not in background or as a demon, but "sometimes" this solution will work.
When downvoting it is nice to explain why

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this please?

```
brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this startup script on Ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     mongodb
# Required-Sart:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description: mongodb
# Description: mongo db server
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PROGRAM=/opt/mongo/bin/mongod
MONGOPID=`ps -ef | grep 'mongod' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

test -x $PROGRAM || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
     log_begin_msg "Starting MongoDB server"
         ulimit -v unlimited.
         ulimit -n 100000
     /opt/mongo/bin/mongod --fork --quiet --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --rest   --config /etc/mongod.conf.
     log_end_msg 0
     ;;
  stop)
     log_begin_msg "Stopping MongoDB server"
     if [ ! -z "$MONGOPID" ]; then
kill -15 $MONGOPID
     fi
     log_end_msg 0
     ;;
  status)
     ;;
  *)
     log_success_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/mongodb {start|stop|status}"
     exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: So you just kill mongoDB directly,right?  I'm a beginner of MongoDB, is there any hurts to kill it?  I know for SQLServer or Oracle, they will meet problems if we just kill them.

Comment: to kill is -9 but -15 u send SIGNAL.

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows

In PowerShell, it's: `Stop-Service MongoDB`

Then to start it again: `Start-Service MongoDB`

To verify whether it's started, run: `net start | findstr MongoDB`.

<sup>Note: Above assumes [MongoDB is registered as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438055/55075).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take advantage of the **Task Manager** provided by your OS for a quick and easy solution. Below is the screengrab from/for Windows 10. Right-click on the highlighted process and select *stop*. Select *start*, if already stopped.

[image]

Please Note: *Internally the commands are doing the same thing which you have to do manually using a GUI (Task Manager), provided by Windows/your OS. Though, this approach to be used for study/practice purpose to get started and you won't be blocked due to this.*

Answer (score 0):

To start
**sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start**

To stop
**sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb stop**

Comment: I believe this is already nicely covered in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776728/4957508)

Answer (score -3):

CTRL + C

on the windows command line