# meaning of sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db

Tags: mongodb, shell, command-line, command

This command is actually a solution for [this question about mongodb issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229412/unable-to-create-open-lock-file-data-mongod-lock-errno13-permission-denied).
But the ichiness of not knowing what exactly it is doing, command by command, is really drive me nut!

If anyone could dissect what this line does to... the /data/db directory, or even any other directory! Will be really appreciated (also those who like me, very noobie in command line)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main command is chown, which itself change the owner of the files.

-R means Recursively, means, its applied to every files in the directory

the command inside ` are execute first and then give the result to previous command

id -u is a single command seperated from chown. You can try it and see the result.

in my computer

```
id -u
```

returns

```
myusername
```

so in my computer

```
sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db
```

is same as

```
sudo chown -R myusername /data/db
```

And now because I own that directory, I can add, edit, delete files within that folders.