# Failing to start mongo on a remote machine that I SSH into

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I'm having some trouble starting up mongo. I am using it on a remote machine that I SSH into where. The remote machine is where I do everything (nothing is done on my own machine). Should I change the bind_ip from 127.0.0.1 to the remote machine's IP address? But regardless of whether I leave the IP as it is or change it to the IP of my remote machine, I get the same error message below:

```
melissa@simba:~$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
melissa@simba:~$ sudo service mongod start
mongod start/running, process 10623
melissa@simba:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
2015-09-24T19:27:55.279+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-09-24T19:27:55.280+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

My remote machine is: Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud x86_64) where the user `melissa` is a sudoer.

And this is the message I get when starting `mongod &`

```
melissa@simba:~$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2015-09-24T19:40:20.706+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10656 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=simba
2015-09-24T19:40:20.707+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.11
2015-09-24T19:40:20.707+0000 [initandlisten] git version: d00c1735675c457f75a12d530bee85421f0c5548
2015-09-24T19:40:20.707+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build4.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-09-24T19:40:20.707+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-09-24T19:40:20.707+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.746+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-09-24T19:40:20.747+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-09-24T19:40:20.747+0000 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2015-09-24T19:40:20.747+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

More info:

```
melissa@simba:~$  ps -edaf | grep mongo
melissa  10748 10555  0 19:45 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo
melissa@simba:~$ service mongod status
status: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
melissa@simba:~$ sudo service mongod status
mongod stop/waiting
melissa@simba:~$ ps -aux | grep mongo
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
melissa  10786  0.0  0.3   8148   904 pts/1    S+   19:47   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
melissa@simba:~$ mongod --shutdown
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

Then I tried to change the permission based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22623543/4825465), but got a new error:

```
melissa@simba:~/meeth-app$ sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db
[sudo] password for melissa:

melissa@simba:~/meeth-app$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
2015-09-25T01:57:54.966+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-09-25T01:57:54.967+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed

melissa@simba:~/meeth-app$ mongod &
[1] 16467
melissa@simba:~/meeth-app$ mongod --help for help and startup options
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16467 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=simba
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.11
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] git version: d00c1735675c457f75a12d530bee85421f0c5548
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build4.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-09-25T01:55:07.366+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-09-25T01:55:07.369+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-09-25T01:55:07.369+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten]
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten]
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.370+0000 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-09-25T01:55:07.371+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-09-25T01:55:07.371+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: The error is in this line: `exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating `

Comment: I tried to terminate mongo, but I still get the same thing.  melissa@simba:~$ mongod --shutdown
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db

Comment: I would like to help you, but unfortunately I am a software developer (like most people on this website). Not an [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) user (or [linux user in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)), [server admin](https://serverfault.com) or [database administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened that made mongo work again. Btw, I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Change the owner of /data from root to mongodb: `sudo chown -R mongodb /data`.

Add a line to turn smallfiles on in `/etc/mongod.conf`: `smallfiles = true`

Do NOT run `mongod &` because it's not running from a place with the right permissions, instead do `sudo service mongod start` and you can open the mongo shell with `mongo`.

Thanks to r05c03 and oldlaptop from freenode irc #linux for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Permission for /data are wrong.  Startup cannot write the PID file or likely the db files either.   Try

sudo chmod -R mongodb /data