# Tweepy script affecting MongoDB service shutting down

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tweepy

I have the following Python script that uses [Tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org) to get tweets and store them into MongoDB using [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/). What's happening is whenever I run this script, my MongoDB instance gets shut down, and the script stops with errors. I have no idea why this would be happening, because even if the script is terminating or Tweepy is encountering errors, it shouldn't be affecting MongoDB's running state. This line is identified as the first trigger point: `stream.filter(locations=[-119.970703, 48.994636, -109.951172, 59.955010])`

**Script**

```
import tweepy, sys, json, traceback
from bson.json_util import loads as json_to_bson
from hashlib import sha1
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from time import sleep, strptime, mktime

client = MongoClient()
mode = None

class Stream(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, data):
        save(data)

    def on_error(self, code):
        pause()

def now():
    return str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

def pause():
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep((60*15)+5)

def save(data):
    bson = json_to_bson(json.dumps(data._json))
    tweet_date = strptime(bson['created_at'], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
    tweet_date = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(tweet_date)))

    bson['created_at'] = tweet_date
    bson['text_hash'] = sha1(bson['text'].encode('punycode')).hexdigest()
    bson['collected_at'] = now()
    bson['collection_type'] = mode

    if client.grebe.tweets.find_one({'text_hash': bson['text_hash']}) == None:
        client.grebe.tweets.insert_one(bson)

def api():
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'key'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'secret'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'tokenkey'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'tokensecret'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return tweepy.API(auth)

def main():
    mystream = Stream()
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api().auth, mystream)
    stream.filter(locations=[-119.970703, 48.994636, -109.951172, 59.955010])

main()
```

**Errors**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter 
    self._start(async)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start 
    self._run()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception

AutoReconnect: connection closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure yet why, but the following answer to a question about permission problems on the MongoDB lock helped solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982017/863923