# Error changing default dbPath for MongoDB on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, mongodb, azure, centos, centos7

How do we change the options like dbPath, path etc in mongod.conf file.
I am using centos 7.
Every time i change the default dbPath and try to restart mongod service it fails.(It works fine with default config options like ->

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
)
```

I have tried changing permissions to new directory using `chown mongod:mongod /path/to/data` and `chmod 0755 /path/to/data`

Every time i get error (in mongod.log file )-> `2017-03-27T06:03:27.182+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /path/to/data, terminating`

Comment: has nothing to do with azure and\or development, probably better off on serverfault

Comment: Probably even better to post on the Unix stack exchange site ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com)). Also, when you post there, probably a good thing to include details of the permissions on the various directories you're targeting, and actually showing the modifications to your `mongod.conf`

Comment: According to the error, it seems a permission issue. Do you check upper folder permissions?  All of the path should be `755`. You could use the command to check `ls -ld /` `ls -ld /path` `ls -ld /path/to` `ls -ld /path/ti/data`

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue?

Comment: Not Yet, Same issue. BTW I just updated the error (exact copy paste from the log file)

Comment: This seems to be the issue with centos only, things seems to be working fine with ubuntu.

Comment: Could you access the data file by using mongod user? `su - mongod`

Comment: @Dheerajvats Do you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229412/unable-to-create-open-lock-file-data-mongod-lock-errno13-permission-denied)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to configure the  /etc/sysconfig/selinux file.
Change 
`SELINUX=enforcing` to 
`SELINUX=disabled` to allow MongoDB to start on CentOS.
You must reboot the system for the changes to take effect.