# Unable to start mongodb as service on linux Ubuntu in digital ocean

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

When I tried starting MongoDB service using "systemctl start mongodb
" command nothing happens.

But when I use mongod command in terminal. The server starts so what should I do to start MongoDB as a service

The output result of mongod and mongo command are in the image link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsGZT.png

I also tried to get the status before using mongod command using "systemctl status mongodb" command in the terminal and below is the output result

*root@lc-1gb-blr1-01:~# systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-07-01 10:49:50 UTC; 3h 49min ago
 Main PID: 8695 (code=exited, status=100)*

Comment: According to the logs you posted, everything just starts perfectly. What is the problem when starting mongod ?

Comment: @Benoit problem is mongodb not starting as a service. I have also added status info now

Comment: Check list...
You stopped mongod before launching the service ?
The user that runs the service has the same rights as the one you use for direct launch of `mongod` ?
Can you post the logs (usually under `/var/log/mongodb.log`) ?

Comment: Thanks, @Benoit i checked log file and found this error "98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied" and solved the problem using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229412/unable-to-create-open-lock-file-data-mongod-lock-errno13-permission-denied