# Uninstall MongoDB on Mac OS X

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

When I try to run mongod from the terminal, I get the following error:

2014-07-02T23:56:24.797-0700 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2014-07-02T23:56:24.797-0700 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use

I recently realize that I have two versions of MongoDB on my Mac, and think this may be the source for the above error.  (Plus, I do not need two version.)  I tried Googling, but was not able to find clear directions on how I can uninstall.  I have development version 2.7.0 AND 2.6.3.

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Comment: if you installed them using `brew` you can `brew uninstall mongo`. To fix your socket issue, kill all mongodb process using `ps aux | grep mongo` to see the processes and `kill -9 process_number` to kill it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, Pierre-Louis.  Unfortunately, still the same issue.  Tried brew uninstall as well as the kill -9 with the number.  Still get ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017.

Comment: After a little more pain, Pierre-Loiuse, pkill -mongod worked.  MongoDB essentially always seems to be running even after terminal close and re-load.  I need to either pkill -mongod on terminal load, OR control-C the running database before exiting terminal.  Thanks again!!

Comment: FYI, if you have a running `mongod` there are more polite ways to shutdown than `kill -9` (which should only be used in extreme desperation). See: [How to stop mongo DB in one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774887/).

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois your comment should have been an answer.

Comment: There is an official guide from MongoDB to uninstall MongoDB from any operating system https://www.mongodb.com/basics/uninstall-mongodb

Answer (score 97):

Run the following commands to remove mongodb from the launch/startup and to uninstall it using Homebrew:

```
# See if mongo is in the launch/startup list
launchctl list | grep mongo

# Remove mongodb from the launch/startup
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb

# Kill the mongod process just in case it's running
pkill -f mongod

# Now you can safely remove mongodb using Homebrew
brew uninstall mongodb
```

Just double-check in `/usr/local/bin/` to make sure that the mongodb commands are removed.

Comment: how should I uninstall it if it is not installed with brew? `Thu Nov 30 04:42:56 :~/CS460_660$ brew uninstall mongodb
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb`

Comment: https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/uninstall-mongodb-macos-completely-d2a6d6c163f9. I felt this was quite useful and comprehensive

Comment: `brew uninstall --force mongodb` to remove all versions.

Comment: What would you recommend doing if the MongoDB commands are still there after running the uninstall?

Comment: I agree with @smc in using https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/uninstall-mongodb-macos-completely-d2a6d6c163f9. I installed mongod differently based on MacOS Sierra. The guide above covered all aspects in removing it.

Comment: Error: No installed keg or cask with the name "mongodb"

Comment: @VipulSharma I had the same issue but I had installed `mongodb-community` rather than `mongodb`, e.g. like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63490095/2037637

Answer (score 24):

For uninstalling the community version, i found that the command `brew uninstall mongodb-community` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

[Nitin Jadhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741251/nitin-jadhav) version worked for me, `brew uninstall mongodb` kept given me `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb`. I was removing a mongodb-community.
use `cd /usr/local/Cellar` then run `ls -a` and then run `rm -rf mongodb-community` to remove it

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest navigating into your `/usr/local/Cellar` and run an `ls -a`, I had a community version of mongo installed that wasn't being picked up by the command given above. If you find any mongo versions there just `rm -rf` each instance

Answer (score 2):

For those having this error in osx:

```
brew uninstall mongodb Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb
```

execute `brew list | grep mongo`

for example, it could show something like:

```
mongodb-community@4.2
mongodb-database-tools
mongosh
```

remove them with `brew uninstall mongodb-community@4.2 mongodb-database-tools mongosh`

Also execute `launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb` as @anuvrat-tiku says in his answer.