# dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN: mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I have just installed mongoDb in my macOs Sierra version 10.12.6 with command `brew install mongodb-community@4.4` and start the service using command `brew services start mongodb-community@4.4`.

I got message "Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu", after which I run the command `mongod` and I got error message:

```
Macs-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ mongod
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6
```

I thought it's happening because of older version of my macOs so, after this I have install and tried with the following but got same error

**brew install mongodb-community@4.4**
**brew install mongodb-community@3.4** and
**brew install mongodb-community@3.2**

but got same error message:

```
Macs-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ mongod
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6
```

What can I try to overcome this?

Comment: (Hi. Please familiarise yourself with the formatting tools here - we use Markdown).

Answer (score 3):

Check [Mongodb macOs installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/), it stated that MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition supports macOS 10.13 or later and this was also stated in the error message you got. I would recommend you install version 4.2

Comment: I have also tried with MongoDB 3.2 Community Edition 
but getting the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running on macOs 10.12.6 (Sierra), seemed like a problem with older macOS version. Had to [remove mongodb via this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33108414), then tried installing mongoDB [via .tgz tarball](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/). That didn't work, same error. Double checked on [supported platforms on mongodb's website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#prod-notes-supported-platforms), seems like 4.2 is still okay. Finally installed and ran in terminal:

`brew install mongodb-community@4.2`

Now it works. I don't know why removing and reinstalling 4.4 then 4.2 worked but it does now.