# How to exit gitbash after running Mongod?

Tags: mongodb, git, npm, command-line-interface, git-bash

I am following some tutorials on how to work with Mongodb but they don't explain how to close the CLI. I usually just use "exit" but after running mongod it now does nothing, and if I try to leave by just closing the window I get a message saying "processes running in session".
I get the same problem with the other gitbash window after running npm run dev (I think the "dev" part is just specific to what I do now?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can press 'ctrl' + 'c' on your keyboard and it should stop the process running on your command line tool.

Have a look here thing might be more MongoDB specific help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776728/4389143

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using ctrl + c but I don't know if that is the best thing to do, as the answer says there are proper was to wait it but none worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The command to save a file in Vim and quit the editor is :wq . To save the file and exit the editor simultaneously, press Esc to switch to normal mode, type :wq and hit Enter .

Check [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-save-file-in-vim-quit-editor/%23:%7E:text%3Dand%2520hit%2520Enter%2520.-,Save%2520a%2520File%2520and%2520Quit%2520Vim%2520%252F%2520Vi,type%2520%253Awq%2520and%2520hit%2520Enter%2520.%26text%3DAnother%2520command%2520to%2520save%2520a%2520file%2520and%2520quit%2520Vim%2520is%2520%253Ax%2520.&ved=2ahUKEwiAxqTvpoPyAhWIRhUIHaD-DxEQFjABegQIAxAF&usg=AOvVaw3YsCRoSftrkb75JyX_6ROv).

Comment: I think the original question has nothing to do with quitting VIM