# How to create service for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

When I use mongodb, I have to perform two steps to start mongodb.

1. start the `mongod` then pass `dbpath`
2. then apply mongo command

But instead of that, is there any other way to ignore this step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run MongoDB as windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service)

Comment: How to configure your database falls outside of the scope of SO and would be better asked on SuperUser or ServerFault. On the other hand, just looking at the [official mongodb guides](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb) would be an awesome start for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/) that has been suggested links to mostly outdated answers.

If you install MongoDB 2.6.1 or newer using the [MSI download](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and an [Administrator Command Prompt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#open-an-administrator-command-prompt), a service definition should automatically be created for you.

The MongoDB documentation also has a tutorial to help you [Manually Create a Windows Service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb) definition if needed.

Comment: I just installed 2.6.3 on Windows 8.1 using the MSI download and it didn't create the service for me.  At least I couldn't find it in the Services list.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Just retested; the service creation wants an [Administrator Command Prompt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#open-an-administrator-command-prompt), otherwise it rather silently fails to create the service. The expected outcome would be for the installer to prompt for admin access if required (or warn explicitly). I'll find or raise a Jira issue to fix this.

Comment: Relevant Jira issue is [SERVER-14263: Installer should install MongoDB as a service on Windows](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14263).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a step 2?

It only launches a mongo client with a user console to connect to the running mongo db process. If you create a linux or windows service don't call mongo

BTW there is such a question already in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service)

Comment: but i have not set any environment variable. that's why

Comment: To run a mongo db server you don't need any environment variable. So I might be missing something in your question.