# Start mongodb when at Windows start up

Tags: windows, mongodb, powershell, service

I am running mongodb on windows and I would like for it to start running when windows starts up.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service

Answer (score 1):

Install it as a Windows service that will run automatically:

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
```

Full list of steps [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb).

Comment: ok i see ty.........