# Starting MongoDB Server Automatically

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, web, web-deployment

I am using mongodb as database and robomongo to access it using GUI. But each time, when i need to access the database, I have to start the mongo server throught cmd. Is there a way to avoid starting the mongo server through cmd.

Or is there way to start mongo server when starting apache server in XAMPP.

Comment: How are you starting mongo server?

Comment: @srahul07 using the cmd and "mongod --dbpath C:\data\db" command

Comment: I think you have to install mongodb as windows service. Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service

Comment: @srahul07 thank you sir

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please comment up by clicking on the gray arrow on left side in front of my comment and above the gray flag.