# MongoDB run and never stop

Tags: mongodb, server, pm2

I installed mongo locally in a windows server 2012, and I would like this mongo is always running because my node project running with pm2, is using this mongo.

How I can do this? I search to do this with pm2 and I found this: pm2-mongodb but it doesnt work.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service

Comment: This is all in the official documentation. [Install MongoDB on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)