# Error parsing command line : unrecognized option '--rest'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to download mongoDB on my windows computer. I am very new to this.

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath 
C:\mongodb\mongodb.log --logappend --rest --install
```

But it was showing the error as on the title. I just started mongoDB and was trying to learn it through tutorials, but now I am stuck.

Comment: Can you run `mongod --version`?

Comment: Yes I actually can run the -- version

Comment: Good. You should take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `--rest` parameter was removed in MongoDB 3.6 as described in this page: [MongoDB Configuration Hardening](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/) and this ticket: [SERVER-29000](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29000).

Remove the `--rest` option from your command line.

Comment: for me removing --rest worked but i also needed to add:
 ```mongod --bind_ip localhost,<ipaddress or hostname>``` 
as mongo 3.6 only listens to localhost by default now

Answer (score 2):

Just Install MongoDb and go to the bin folder and run `mongo` using cmd to start the server. By default, data will be stored to `c:\data\db` (create a folder).

Also if you have gitbash installed you can set aliases to run using gitbash.

Run following command:

```
cd~
touch .bash_profile
vi .bash_profile
```

now it will open vim editor press `i` and type:

```
alias mongod="/c/Program\ files/MongoDB/Server/{version}/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/{version}/bin/mongo.exe"
```

remember to replace `{version}` with your installed version.

Press `esc` and type `:wq!` and press enter to exit.

Now you can run `mongo` and `mongod` commands from any directory on gitbash.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the --rest parameter but it doesn't work. 
After I run "net start MongoDB", it gaves me this message:
"The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I am now running into this same issue.