# How to set mongo db path permanently

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to over-rite the mongodb default db path. Even after editing the storage path in mongod.conf to the custom directory path. Still it looks for **/data/db**, and not the custom path.

Since every time mongod path needs to be specified for the custom path.

> mongod --dbpath /Users/customData

Is there a permanent way to deal this.

Comment: Did you use `--config` to specify the path to `mongod.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it as a service, so that you don't need to run this command everytime you want to use it, and it runs it in the path you set it to

Here's how:
[the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-to-run-mongodb-as-windows-service)

from official mongodb website: [the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of MongoDB

> To run a mongod process as a daemon (i.e. fork), and write its output
>   to a log file, use the --fork and --logpath options. You must create
>   the log directory; however, mongod will create the log file if it does
>   not exist.
>
> The following command starts mongod as a daemon and records log output
>   to /var/log/mongodb.log.
>
> mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log