# How to start mongodb service for windows

Tags: mongodb

How can I run my mongo db service on windows 10

I have downloaded mongo db. tried coping data files in required directories . Whenever I try start mongodb service from task manager->services it shows windows could not start mongo db service.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation about how to install and run MonogDB in window. [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Secondly this question is also asked before you can get help from [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-can-i-run-mongodb-as-a-windows-service).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have installed MongoDB in your window OS and make sure you have set the environment variable for MongoDB.

To start MongoDB server - type 'mongod' in command prompt.

[Start MongoDB server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYT3h.png)

To start client - type 'mongo' in command prompt.

[Start MongoDB client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqJLl.png)