# I Can't Connect to localhost in NoSQL Manager for MongoDB (Error!)

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, nosql

I get an error when I want to connect to local hosts

I read more answer but I couldn't fix this error

- excuse me for my bad English :)

Error:

```
Establishing connection to 'localhost:27017'...
Connecting to 'localhost' host...
NoSQL Manager advice:
Probably server is not listening at the location specified, the tool can’t connect to it.
Fixing this problem involves starting the server at the specified location or allowing it through a firewall.

Error:
"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017

Details:
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "2", ConnectionMode : "Direct", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 2, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<CreateStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__28.MoveNext()" }] }.
```

[This is my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE30l.png)

Please Help me :)

Comment: Did you start your Mongo Service ? It looks like you haven't.

Comment: how to start this? 

Comment: If Linux: sudo service mongod start,

If windows : Follow This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438055/how-can-i-run-mongodb-as-a-windows-service